# How can I get a POSIXTime in the Contract monad?

Tags: plutus, smart-contract

I don't see any way to use `IO` in `Contract` and I don't see any functions for getting a `POSIXTime` from the things I can get within `Contract`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a `currentTime` function in `Plutus.Contract.Request` with the signature

```
currentTime :: forall w s e. AsContractError e => Contract w s e POSIXTime
```